# Biblatex/Biber: Comma before "in" after title

Tags: biblatex, biber

I want to achieve something like this:

> Stachelhaus, Thomas: „Ist er noch wer, wenn er nicht mehr er ist?“ –
>   Identität und Identitätsverlust in Franz Kafkas ‚Die Verwandlung‘ und
>   Paul Austers ‚Stadt aus Glas‘**, in:** Schlicht, Corinna (Hrsg.):
>   Identität. Oberhausen: Verlag Karl Maria Laufen 2010 (Autoren im
>   Kontext – Duisburger Studienbögen Bd. 11), S. 122–136.

This is where I am:

> Stachelhaus, Thomas: "Ist er noch wer, wenn er nicht mehr er ist?" –
>   Identität und Identitätsverlus in Franz Kafkas ’Die Verwandlung’ und
>   Paul Austers ’Stadt aus Glas’**. In:** Schlicht, Corinna (Hrsg.):
>   Identität. Bd. 11. Oberhausen: Verlag Karl Maria Laufen 2010 (Autoren
>   im Kontext – Duisburger Studienbögen) Bd. 11, S. 122–136.

I do not want a comma after the title in general but only if there is a "in:" (which should be lower case also) and so far I got that for the types article and InCollection.

This is my exemplary bib:

```
@InCollection{Stachelhaus.2010,
  Title                    = {{\dq}Ist er noch wer, wenn er nicht mehr er ist?{\dq} -- Identit{\"a}t und Identit{\"a}tsverlus in Franz Kafkas 'Die Verwandlung' und Paul Austers 'Stadt aus Glas'},
  Author                   = {Stachelhaus, Thomas},
  Booktitle                = {Identit{\"a}t},
  Publisher                = {Verlag Karl Maria Laufen},
  Year                     = {2010},
  Address                  = {Oberhausen},
  Editor                   = {Schlicht, Corinna},
  Pages                    = {122--136},
  Series                   = {Autoren im Kontext -- Duisburger Studienb{\"o}gen},
  Volume                   = {11},
}
```

I hope an MWE isn't need here and if it's important I'm using the style ibid-verbose.

Thanks so much in advance for your help :-)

P.S.: I know that there are some problems with the volume which I hope will be resolved here: [Biblatex/Biber: Put series, volume and number at the end](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269999/biblatex-biber-put-series-volume-and-number-at-the-end/270432)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the way `biblatex`'s punctuation tracker works, we can - with a bit of cheating - avoid patching the drivers.

```
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printtext{%
    \bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}
```

We simply replace the punctuation currently in the punctuation buffer with `\addcomma\space`, the buffer is used immediately afterwards, because a `\printtext` directive follows.

MWE

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@InCollection{Stachelhaus.2010,
  title     = {\enquote{Ist er noch wer, wenn er nicht mehr er ist?} -- Identit{\"a}t und Identit{\"a}tsverlus in Franz Kafkas \enquote{Die Verwandlung} und Paul Austers \enquote{Stadt aus Glas}},
  author    = {Stachelhaus, Thomas},
  booktitle = {Identit{\"a}t},
  publisher = {Verlag Karl Maria Laufen},
  year      = {2010},
  address   = {Oberhausen},
  editor    = {Schlicht, Corinna},
  pages     = {122--136},
  series    = {Autoren im Kontext -- Duisburger Studienb{\"o}gen},
  number    = {11},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printtext{%
    \bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Note that in the MWE I have changed your hand-drawn quotation marks to `csquotes`' `\enquote` and ended the abuse of the `volume` field, where `number` should be used.

[image: output of MWE]

Comment: strangely this does not change anything for me, but thanks so much anyway for your fast answer :-)

Comment: @Sickboy Well that will have to do with your other modifications, then. If you are interested in an investigation, you will need to provide more information about the modifications you already apply. (Especially if you have your own `\renewbibmacro*{in:}` clause).

Comment: you are absolutely right. I just noticed that I had no "in:" before the journal title and saw that it was because I already had a `\renewbibmacro*{in:}` clause. I had that because I wanted to have the editors in front of the (book) title. Now I combined both to:
 `\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printtext{%
    \bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}
 \usebibmacro{ineditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \clearname{editor}}`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small patch for the `InCollection`driver. You will probably have to do thesame for all drivers that use the `in:` macro:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@InCollection{Stachelhaus.2010,
  Title = {{\dq}Ist er noch wer, wenn er nicht mehr er ist?{\dq} -- Identit{\"a}t und Identit{\"a}tsverlus in Franz Kafkas 'Die Verwandlung' und Paul Austers 'Stadt aus Glas'},
  Author = {Stachelhaus, Thomas},
  Booktitle = {Identit{\"a}t},
  Publisher = {Verlag Karl Maria Laufen},
  Year = {2010},
  Address = {Oberhausen},
  Editor = {Schlicht, Corinna},
  Pages = {122--136},
  Series = {Autoren im Kontext -- Duisburger Studienb{\"o}gen},
  Volume = {11},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}{%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Still a very useful answer from @moewe. I now wanted to get from:

> Babka, Anna: Frauen.Schreiben – Jelinek-Lesen. Aspekte einer allo-écriture (féminine) in Texten Elfriede Jelineks (nach Hélène Cixous, Luce Irigaray und Julia Kristeva), in: Julian Müller und Liu Wei (Hrsg.): Frauen.Schreiben. Wien: Praesens Verlag 2014 (Österreichische Literatur in China, Bd. 2), S. 17–52.

to

> Babka, Anna: Frauen.Schreiben – Jelinek-Lesen. Aspekte einer allo-écriture (féminine) in Texten Elfriede Jelineks (nach Hélène Cixous, Luce Irigaray und Julia Kristeva), in: Frauen.Schreiben, hrsg.v. Liu Wei und Julian Müller. Wien: Praesens Verlag 2014 (Österreichische Literatur in China, Bd. 2), S. 17–52.

and achieved this using this code:

```
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}% <---- this is new ...
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}%}% <---- and this

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{% 
  byeditor={hrsg\adddot\thinspace v\adddotspace}, 
  } 

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printtext{%
    \bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}
```

Just in case somone wants to achieve something similar (and wants to ovrride "ed. by", `DefineBibliographyStrings` line).

In case someone is wondering, this is the coressponding bib entry:

```
@InCollection{Babka2014,
  author    = {Babka, Anna},
  title     = {Frauen.Schreiben -- Jelinek-Lesen. Aspekte einer allo-\'{e}criture (f\'{e}minine) in Texten Elfriede Jelineks (nach H\'{e}l\`{e}ne Cixous, Luce Irigaray und Julia Kristeva)},
  booktitle = {Frauen.Schreiben},
  publisher = {Praesens Verlag},
  year      = {2014},
  editor    = {Liu Wei and Julian Müller},
  series    = {Österreichische Literatur in China, Bd. 2},
  pages     = {17--52},
  address   = {Wien},
}
```