# Put series after totalpages

Tags: biblatex, biber

I would like to put the series item at the real end of the line, after the total pages.

Here, I found how to put it after the date: [Biblatex/Biber: Put series, volume and number at the end](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269999/biblatex-biber-put-series-volume-and-number-at-the-end)

with this code:

```
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printfield{series}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \printfield{number}%
       \newunit}}}
\newcommand*\patchseries[1]{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
    {}
    {}
    {\typeout{Warning: Failed to remove series+number from driver #1.}}
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}}
    {\usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{series+number}}
    {}
    {\typeout{Warning: Failed to add series+number to driver #1.}}}
\patchseries{book}\patchseries{inbook}
\patchseries{collection}\patchseries{incollection}
\patchseries{proceedings}\patchseries{inproceedings}
\DeclareFieldFormat{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}
```

But, for this

```
@BOOK{laplantine1999,
  keywords = {livre},
  entrysubtype = {ouvrages},
  title = {Je, nous et les autres},
  publisher = {Le Pommier},
  year = {1999},
  author = {LAPLANTINE, François},
  address = {Paris},
  series = {Manifeste},
  pagetotal = {162}
 }
```

the result is like this :

> LAPLANTINE, François. Je, nous et les autres, Paris : Le Pommier, 1999, (coll. Manifeste), 162 p.

and I would like :

> LAPLANTINE, François. Je, nous et les autres, Paris : Le Pommier, 1999, 162 p. (coll. Manifeste)

Comment: Can you show us an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)? It would be important to know what style you use and what other modifications you apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Kafka.2001,
  Title                    = {Die Verwandlung},
  Author                   = {Kafka, Franz},
  Publisher                = {Philipp Reclam},
  Year                     = {2001},
  Address                  = {Stuttgart},
  Number                   = {9900},
  Series                   = {Reclams Universal-Bibliothek}
}
@BOOK{laplantine1999,
  keywords = {livre},
  entrysubtype = {ouvrages},
  title = {Je, nous et les autres},
  publisher = {Le Pommier},
  year = {1999},
  author = {LAPLANTINE, François},
  address = {Paris},
  series = {Manifeste},
  pagetotal = {162}
 }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printfield{series}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \printfield{number}%
       \newunit}}}

\newcommand*\patchseries[1]{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
    {}
    {}
    {\typeout{Warning: Failed to remove series+number from driver #1.}}
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}}
    {\usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{series+number}}
    {}
    {\typeout{Warning: Failed to add series+number to driver #1.}}}

\patchseries{book}\patchseries{inbook}
\patchseries{collection}\patchseries{incollection}
\patchseries{proceedings}\patchseries{inproceedings}

\DeclareFieldFormat{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}

\begin{document}
\blockcquote{Kafka.2001}{Als Gregor Samsa eines Morgens aus unruhigen Träumen erwachte, fand er sich in seinem Bett zu einem ungeheueren Ungeziefer verwandelt.}.

\nocite{sigfridsson,worman,brandt,baez/article,laplantine1999}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The only change is

```
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}}
    {\usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{series+number}}
    {}
    {\typeout{Warning: Failed to add series+number to driver #1.}}
```

instead of

```
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}}
    {\usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{series+number}}
    {}
    {\typeout{Warning: Failed to add series+number to driver #1.}}
```

This moves the series even further to the back.

Comment: @BertrandPinletEedf If the answer helped you, please consider accepting it using the checkmark (and upvote it if you have the reputation to do so).